# List all files with sizes in Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've been trying to create a google apps script to list all the files in my drive along with size and email them to me. Partially this is practice and probably useful. This is my code so far:

```
function listAllFiles () {
  var rootFolder = DocsList.getRootFolder();
  var contents = rootFolder.getFiles();
  var file = DocsList.getAllFiles();
  for (i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {

Logger.log(file[i].getName() + ":::" + file[i].getSize());
}
 var recipient = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
 var subject = 'A list of files in your Google Drive';
 var body = Logger.getLog();
 MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
}
```

It only sends lists about 5 files however, unless I change the "contents.length" to a manual number like 100. (Also for some reason it will throw an error on .getName if I make it something high like 1000). Anyway I know I shouldn't be using a hard number. Please bear with my ignorance, I've been learning google scripts about 1 week now and javascript about 2 months on my own.

Comment: You should formulate a definite question somewhere. This makes it easier to get answers because other users don't have to read the text multiple times to get what exactly is unclear.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll keep it short and to the point from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. DriveApp is recommended rather than DocsList
2. DocsList.getAllFiles() is limited by MAX_RESULT_SIZE ... use getAllFilesForPaging(number, token) if you have many files
3. You are only getting the number of files in root from your collection of all files
4. Try

   ```
   function listAllFiles () {
    // DriveApp is recommended rather than DocsList.
     var dFiles = DriveApp.getFiles();
     while (dFiles.hasNext()) {
     var thisFile = dFiles.next()
     Logger.log(thisFile.getName()  + ":::" + thisFile.getSize());

     }
   // you might want to make this restartable if you have lots of files ... time out
    var recipient = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var subject = 'A list of files in your Google Drive';
    var body = Logger.getLog();
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
   }
   ```